# Infinite series for the arctangent from the tangent of half-angle formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, math-history

From Hodge's biography of Turing:

> He had found the infinite series for the "inverse tangent function", starting from the trigonometrical formula for $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)$.*

The footnote states that he used no calculus and and also that "Perhaps the most remarkable thing was his seeing that such a series should exist at all."

So how do you get the infinite series for the inverse tangent from the half-angle formula for the tangent?

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be very difficult to do without calculus. If it's really possible I think it has to involve some kind of recurrence relationship. The problem is that the taylor series for $\arctan x$ looks like $x-x^3/3+x^5/5-x^7/7+\cdots$ which clearly doesn't just pop out of any obvious geometric series expansion.

Comment: To see that the series exists in the first place is *incredible* and the only thing I can say is 'Well he's *Turing*'. But given an infinite series is possible say $\arctan x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$, we can use the identity $2\arctan x = \arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ and equate coefficients after writing down both sides as an infinite series should tell what $a_n's$ are.

Comment: Here is a [link to Google books](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=HyMcH_9eTtoC&pg=PA25&dq=hodge+turing+inverse+tangent+function) for a fuller reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.

My math skills are poor at best, but there are just a couple of things I'm wondering about:

a) The answers given start from the double-angle formula, although the book states that Turing started from the half-angle formula. This seems just peculiar to me.

b) Both answers assume that he would have known about the power series. Wouldn't this be at odds with the quoted part of the footnote?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed using $2\arctan x = \arctan \dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}$ is the way to go.

To simplify things, lets also assume that $\arctan x$ is odd, so $\arctan x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n+1}$.

Then, using the Generalized Binomial Theorem, a change of indices, and a change of order of summation, he could have gotten:

$\arctan \dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\left(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)^{2k+1} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k2^{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(1-x^2)^{-(2k+1)}$.

$= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k2^{2k+1}x^{2k+1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dbinom{2k+n}{2k}x^{2n} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_k2^{2k+1}\dbinom{2k+n}{2k}x^{2n+2k+1}$

$= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n' = k}^{\infty}a_k2^{2k+1}\dbinom{n'+k}{2k}x^{2n'+1} = \sum_{n'=0}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{k = 0}^{n'}a_k2^{2k+1}\dbinom{n'+k}{2k}\right]x^{2n'+1}$.

Hence, $2a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_k2^{2k+1}\dbinom{n+k}{2k}$, i.e. $a_n = -\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}-2}\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}2^{2k+1}\dbinom{n+k}{2k}a_k$ for $n \ge 1$.

Since multiplying the series $a_n$ by any constant won't change the relationship $2\arctan x = \arctan \dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}$, Turing would have also needed the initial term $a_0 = 1$.

From here, it is pretty easy to crank out the first few terms $a_1 = -\dfrac{1}{3}$, $a_2 = \dfrac{1}{5}$, $a_3 = -\dfrac{1}{7}$, etc. and guess that $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$. Although I'm not sure how he would have proven that $-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}-2}\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}2^{2k+1}\dbinom{n+k}{2k}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.

Comment: (+1) Nice ! :) I also had no idea how Turing managed to derive the last identity ! (it's obvious by generating functions though ! :) ..)

Comment: Turing supposedly discovered this at the age of fourteen or fifteen, while still a schoolboy, so while this answer is considerably more advanced than mine, perhaps mine is closer to what Turing might have done.

Comment: Perhaps there is a combinatorical argument for the last identity.

Answer (score 1):

If we say 
$$
\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
then  using $\tan x\approx x$ for small $x$, we get $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$.

Now using @r9m's insight (see comment under question)
$$
2\arctan x=\arctan {2x\over 1-x^2}=\sum a_n2^nx^n(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)^n
$$
For the $x^2$ term the factors are
$$
2a_2x^2=a_2(2x)^2
$$
thus $a_2=0$. Equating terms of $x^3$ gets
$$
2a_3x^3=a_3(2x)^3-2a_1x^3
$$
which gives us
$a_3=-1/3$. You can go on and on with this to get $a_4$ and $a_5$ etc. Turing may have noticed a pattern, gone further and worked out a recurrence relation.